# Xshell's color scheme don't display correctly in GNU-Screen

Tags: linux, gnu-screen

In my Xshell, every thing is like this:

[image: XShell]

But when I get into gnu-screen, my color fade to grey...

[image: gnu-screen]

I googled, and find `By default, screen uses an 8-color terminal emulator.` in this [archlinux wiki page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNU_Screen).

I have tried all of the solution given by that wiki page and didn't work...

So could any one save me from that gray world?

Of course, for some reason, I have to use screen...

Answer (score 1):

Xshell has it's own color schemes.
You can find them under Tools > Color Schemes

That's why it's different.
Do you have any .bashrc and LS_COLORS setup in your system?
Try installing [LS_COLORS](https://github.com/trapd00r/LS_COLORS) under your home directory and maybe try again?

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same problem, and solved it by adding `term xterm` to ~/.screenrc